# How to get the size of a materialized view in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to know how can I get the size of a materialized view I created in oracle and also the cost of creating the materialized view if possible.

For example how to get the size of this view (storage used by this view), the name of the database is studentDB.

```
create materialized view mv_name
as
select * from student;
```

Comment: Materialialized views are implemented as a *table* with the same name. You are looking for *table size*.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `DBA_SEGMENTS` or `USER_SEGMENTS` dictionary view as follows:

```
SELECT SEGMENT_NAME,
       SEGMENT_TYPE,
       BYTES / 1024 / 1024 MB
  FROM DBA_SEGMENTS
 WHERE SEGMENT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
   AND SEGMENT_NAME = '<yourviewname>';
```

Materialized view creates the table with the same name as the Materialized view name.

Comment: I'm getting `no rows selected` even though the view exists

Comment: Thanks it worked after I removed `SEGMENT_TYPE` from the select statement and used group by on `SEGMENT_NAME`

Comment: `BYTES / 1024 / 1024` should be rather `MiB`, see [Binary Prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)

Comment: SELECT SEGMENT_NAME,
       SEGMENT_TYPE,
       BYTES / 1024 / 1024 MB
  FROM DBA_SEGMENTS
 WHERE SEGMENT_NAME = 'my_view_name';

It worked for me.